# удалить пробел из строки в переменной PHP

Tags: php, php7

есть такой кусок кода

```
$pric = $html->find('html body div span[class=price__value]', 0); // цена товара
$pric = strip_tags($pric); // обрезаю лишние хтмл теги

$pric = preg_replace('%^\s+|\s+$%u', '', $pric); // здесь должна быть цена без пробелов (но они есть)
```

парсингом `$html = new simple_html_dom();` вытаскиваю цену товара, но внутри цены присутствует пробел, в итоге у меня берет цифры до пробела (если тысячи) и нормально если пробела нет. для работы использую пхп 7.3

получаю `39&nbsp;999`

в источнике выглядит так же
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

использовал уже все известные регулярки, с различной кодировкой, без толку. не помогло ничего.
может кто подскажет решение проблемы? кто сталкивался уже с таким

```
$pric = html_entity_decode($pric); 
echo $pric. "<br>"; 
$pric = preg_replace('%&nbsp;%u', '', $pric); 
echo $pric. "<br>"; // выводим цену
```

и все остается так же как и было. пробел на месте
пы.сы. из последнего, попробовал заменить пробел на "-", видит пробел в конце строки, а не в середине (между цифрами)

Comment: `$pric = preg_replace('%&nbsp;%u', '', $pric);` или `$pric = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $pric);`?

Comment: `html_entity_decode`

Comment: $pric = html_entity_decode($pric);
echo $pric. "<br>";
$pric = preg_replace('%&nbsp;%u', '', $pric);
echo $pric. "<br>";  // выводим цену   и все остается так же как и было. пробел на месте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$s = '39&nbsp;999';
$v = preg_replace(
    // убираем все что НЕ цифры, 
    // так как &nbsp; декодируется 
    // НЕ в пробел, а другую сущность 
    '/\D+/',
    '',
    html_entity_decode($s)
);

echo $v;
```

Или

```php
$s = '39&nbsp;999';
$v = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $s);

echo $v;
```

[Фидл](https://3v4l.org/g36An)

Comment: первый вариант у меня вывел 24749425239999 вот такое число.. откуда взялось 247494252 понятия пока не имею... но уже близко к решению. второй вариант все так же, ничего не поменял

Comment: Я не вижу исходной строки, поэтому ничего не могу сказать. В фидле все прекрасно работает со строкой указанного формата.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/IKP7B

Comment: Это естественно не работает. Хотя бы потому что `include("file.php")` нечего инклюдить.

Comment: А `2474...` берется из атрибутов `<span class="price__value" style="font-size:24px;" data-v-7b494252="">39&nbsp;999</span>`. Определись, что ты там передаешь в `preg_replace`. И скорее всего у сущности, возвращаемой `$html->find()` есть какой нибудь метод, возвращающий ее текст.

Comment: где в коде include("file.php") ?? там  include('simple_html_dom.php'); вы просили код показать, я показал. как в фидл добавить инклудом симпл я не в курсе

Comment: все отлично.. 
$pric = strip_tags($pric); 
$pri = preg_replace(
    '/\D+/',
    '',
    html_entity_decode($pric)
);

echo $pri. "<br>"; // выводим цену

Comment: магическим образом преобразует 1.5доллара в 15.

Comment: или 99.90рублей в 9990 :)